# How to view content of a file in FTP with RFC 959 implementation?

Tags: ftp, new-operator, implementation, rfc

Is there a way to display file content in the new implementation RETR filename.txt

The old way was:  GET filename.txt -

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer.  With RAW FTP commands, before issue RETR , use PASV, the response will give info about the portnum of data channel, use that info to connect to that port to view the content of the file